# TFHpple parsing link

Tags: ios, hpple

How do you parse a link in TFhpple. My code returns an empty array.

```
NSString *link2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/html/body/table/tr[%d]/td[1]/a",i+2];
 NSArray *linkedNames = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:link2];
             NSLog(@"%@", linkedNames);
```

the soure code for the information is:

```
 <td style="font-size: 12.0pt; color: black; font-weight: 400; text-decoration: none; text-underline-style: none; font-family: Arial Narrow; font-style: normal; text-align: general; vertical-align: bottom; white-space: nowrap; border-left: medium none; border-right: 1.0pt solid windowtext; border-top: medium none; border-bottom: 1.0pt solid windowtext; padding-left: 1px; padding-right: 1px; padding-top: 1px; background: #EAF1DD" width="327">
    <a href="race_announcements/12.22.12RA.pdf">Pat Harty Memorial</a></td>
```

how do I access the string "pat hardy memorial"?

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but I think the problem may be that you are trying to use an xml parser to parse a pdf file. The actual content of the pdf may not be in the html. If you provide a link I may be of more help. Cheers.

edit: well this will give you the label of events with pdfs including the pat hardy memorial.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.nhara.org/scored_races-2013.htm"];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
TFHpple *parser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:urlData];
NSString *propertyXpathQueryString = @"//td/a";
NSArray *propertiesNodes = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:propertyXpathQueryString];

NSMutableArray *list =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init];
for (TFHppleElement *element in propertiesNodes) {

    [list addObject:string];

    string = [[element firstChild] content];


}
for (int i = 0; i < [list count]; i++) {
    NSLog([list objectAtIndex:i]);
}
}
```

Also, here is a good tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

Comment: I am not trying to get the pdf file, I just want the label. the link is http://www.nhara.org/scored_races-2013.htm

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...

```
for(TFHppleElement* element in linkedNames) {

    NSString* label = [element content];
}
```